# React zmq on symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

It looks like there is no way to install react zmq library on a symfony 4 project. trying to install it via composer I get that evenement/evenement does not meet the requirements.

Is there a way to use zmq library on such a project right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the only solution seems to be to downgrade evenement. This solved the issue.